Linuxのsystemdでプログラムを自動起動したい
大学でラズパイを使った研究をしている者です。タイトルの通り、作ったプログラムを、ラズパイ本体起動時に自動で実行してくれるようにしたいです。当初はcronでやろうとしてましたが、@rebootがなかったのと、定期実行だとプログラムが止まってしまうため、systemdでの自動実行を試みています。しかし、いくつかのサイトを参考に下記のように書いてみたものの、うまく動いてくれません。
[Unit]
Description = auto attendance management system

[Service]
ExecStart = /media/admin/A11E-91494/raspresarch/Gakuseisyo.py
Restart = on-failure
Type = simple

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target

この状態で、enableにしても、Active:failedとなってしまいます。
statusを見てみると、
autoboot.service: Failed whit result 'exit-code'

とあったので調べてみたところ、SELinuxによる権限エラーの可能性が高いそうなので、これを無効化するコマンドやら、ファイルの書き換えやらを試しました。しかし、
SELUNUX=disabele

にしても何も変わらず、getenforceなどのコマンドは、bashされてしまいます。
初学者の私には、これ以上サイトで調べても解決できそうにありません。もしかしたら、そもそもの前提が違う可能性もありますが、ご容赦ください。最終目標は、プログラムを本体起動時に自動で実行することであるため、それがかなうならsystemdでなくても構いません。有識者の知識をお借りできますよう、お願いいたします。

少なくとも、ファイルを書き換えた SELUNUX= はタイプミスですよね？ (正しくは SELINUX= ) / また、RasPi はあくまで「ハードウェア」の名前なので、使用している OS の情報も載せておいた方が回答が付きやすいと思います。

もう一点、実行しようとしているファイルのパスが /media/ 以下になっていますが、外部ストレージに保存しているとなるとサービスの起動順によってはマウント準備ができる前に実行しようとして失敗している可能性もあります。いったん別のパス = ローカルに保存した状態で試してみてはどうでしょうか？

Raspberry Pi OS や Ubuntu をご利用なさっているという前提で、systemd を使う選択はそれで良さそうです。その上で service の起動に失敗しているのは、実装したアプリケーション固有の理由があるか、service の起動順に依存関係の問題があるか、そのあたりが多いです。まずはログやステータス情報を確認し、なぜエラーになっているのかを調べるのが良いです。
既に OS を起動したあとに手動で sudo systemctl start ＜service名＞ したあとエラー終了するようであれば、sudo journalctl -xe ＜service名＞ でログが見れるはずなのでどんなエラーが出ているか確認してみてください。もし今回実装したプログラムが全然ログを出さないようであれば、まずログを出すように調整してみてください。Raspberry Pi とのことなので何かしらに書き込みできなくてエラーになるなど、普段お使いのパソコンでは起こらない理由でエラーになっている可能性もあります。

ご回答ありがとうございます。回答者様のおっしゃる通りにログを確認したところ、File is neither a device node,nor regular file,nor executableというエラーログが出ました。訳してみましたが、ファイルはデバイスノードでも、通常ファイルでも、実行可能ファイルでもない、とのことでした。これはつまり、systemdで実行できない形式のファイルということなのでしょうか？

エラーログを省略せずに全部読むようにしてみてください。今書かれているログだと "File" が何のことなのかはっきりしません。systemd で実行しようとしているファイルのことかもしれないし、ログファイルのことかもしれないし、いくつか可能性が考えられます。（systemd のソースコードを読みに行けば分かりそうな気もしますが、とりあえず。）

毎度情報が不足しており申し訳ございません。Fileというのはおそらくautoboot.service、つまり私が本質問で記載したファイル自体がエラーの対象ということです。

エラーメッセージの続きにファイル名が書かれていませんか？　／　また、仮にサービスファイルが読めないのであればまずはそのファイルが正しく systemd が管理するディレクトリに配置されているかをご確認ください。「そんなサービスは無い」というエラーではなく「そんなファイルは無い」というエラーなのでサービスファイルは見つかっている状態な気はしますが……。

返信が遅くなり申し訳ありません。'File is neither a device node,nor regular file,nor executable: /etc/systemd/system/autoboot.service'というのが、journalctlを実行した時のエラー全文です。

うーむ、その場合、エラーメッセージに書いてあるとおり autoboot.service が通常のファイル等になっていなくておかしいか、autoboot.service を実行ファイルとして誤って参照しようとしているところがあるか、そのあたりが怪しいです。まずは /etc/systemd/system/autoboot.service が通常のファイルとして存在するかどうかを確認してみてください。
